# Stop IOS animations appearing all at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I have heard that IOS will batch animations.

for example, I have about 4 methods thats do some updates (on main thread) and when they are done, I call a method to fade in a image of a check mark showing its complete. (see below) However it seems they all appear at the same time.  How could I make them appear after each method call?

```
[mySubClass1 UpdateAllGeneralData_Single];
[self FadeImageGeneralInfo];

[mySubClass1 UpdateAllMeetingData_Single];
[self FadeImageMeetingList];

[mySubClass1 UpdateAllSpeakerData_Single];
[self FadeImageSpeakerList];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a timer to delay each subsequent call to `FadeImage____List` by a certain amount, or you could use the `UIView` `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` class method to delay each subsequent animation.

If you choose option 2, the easiest way to implement it is probably to change `FadeImage______List` to accept a delay argument. Then, for example (if each animation took 0.5 seconds):

```
[mySubClass1 UpdateAllGeneralData_Single];
[self FadeImageGeneralInfoWithDelay:0];

[mySubClass1 UpdateAllMeetingData_Single];
[self FadeImageMeetingListWithDelay:0.5];

[mySubClass1 UpdateAllSpeakerData_Single];
[self FadeImageSpeakerListWithDelay:1.0];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new at much of this.  What would the delay method look like?

Comment: ...or use the "completion:" block to chain the animations

Comment: @epatel The reason I did not recommend using the completion block is because it looks like the OP is trying to separate their model and view code by performing updates to the model and then animating the view in three separate chunks. In order to chain through the completion block, the animation code would need to be brought into the controller and called inline with the model updates.